# Cycle post request in postman

Tags: testing, post, asp.net-web-api, web, postman

I need to test my Web api. I use Postman for sending requests to urls. Can I do it in a loop ? Example : 10 times send request on url_1, if got error - stop sending, else - 10 times send request on url_2 ect. Can I do it with Postman ?

Answer (score 1):

Postman's Collection Runner can be used to specify the [number of iterations](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/starting_a_collection_run#iterations). Furthermore, using Postman's CLI companion [`newman`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) your requirment can be achieved using `--bail` and `--iteration-count` flags:

```
newman run some_collection.json --iteration-count 10 --bail failure
```

where

> `--bail [optional modifiers]` Specify whether or not to stop a collection run on encountering the first test script error.
>
> `--iteration-count <number>` Specifies the number of times the collection has to be run